# I made this code to make a tic-tac-toe game without a GUI in PYTHON

Tags: python, pycharm, tic-tac-toe

I made this code on tic-tac-toe in python and after iterating it works fine but in between the computer stops giving input. My code involves a user vs computer game. Please help me I know my code doesn't contain comments but I hope you will understand and I am a beginner so please help me!!!

In this code, the computer first asks you a choice to take `O` or `X` and then does a toss in which you enter 1 or 0 and compares it to a variable that has a random value between 1 and 0. Then according to toss either the user plays first or the computer.

For computer I used the `randint()` function so that it chooses the row and column in which it places `X` or `O`. In every iteration the code checks whether the random row or column computer gets does not matches with the already filled ones. So this is all about this code!!

```py
import random
row1=None
column1=None
row2 = None
column2 = None
data1=[]
data2=[]
data3=[]
data4=[]
count=0
count2=0
print("Welcome to TIC-TAC-TOE!!")
tic=input("Enter O or X as your choice --> ")
if tic=='O':
    tac='X'
else:
    tac='O'
block=[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]
i=0
choice=int(input("Enter 1 for Head and 0 for Tail --> "))
x=random.randint(0,1)
if choice==x:
    print("You won the toss you get the first chance : ")
    print("## Enter the row and column you want to put your choice in ##")
    row1=int(input("Row --> "))
    data1.append(row1)
    column1=int(input("Column --> "))
    data2.append(column1)
    block[row1-1][column1-1]=tic
    print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
    print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
    print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
    while True:
        i+=1
        if block[0][0]==block[0][1] and block[0][1]==block[0][2] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[1][0]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[1][2] and block[1][0]!=' ':
            if block[1][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print('you Lose!!')
            break
        elif block[2][0]==block[2][1] and block[2][1]==block[2][2] and block[2][0]!=' ':
            if block[2][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][0]==block[1][0] and block[1][0]==block[2][0] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][1]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][1] and block[0][1]!=' ':
            if block[0][1]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][2]==block[1][2] and block[1][2]==block[2][2] and block[0][2]!=' ':
            if block[0][2]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][0]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][2] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][2]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][0] and block[0][2]!=' ':
            if block[0][2]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif i%2!=0:
            print("## A.I ##")
            if row2!=None and column2!=None:
                row2=random.randint(1,3)
                data3.append(row2)
                index1+=1
                length1=len(data3)
                for j in data1:
                    if row2==j:
                        count+=1
                for k in range(0,index1):
                    if row2==data3[k]:
                        count2+=1
                while count>0 or count2>0:
                    row2=random.randint(1,3)
                    for j in data1:
                        if row2 == j:
                            count += 1
                    for k in range(0, index1):
                        if row2 == data3[k]:
                            count2 += 1
                data3[index1]=row2
                column2=random.randint(1,3)
                data4.append(column2)
                index2+=1
                length2=len(data4)
                count=0
                count2=0
                for j in data2:
                    if row2==j:
                        count+=1
                for k in range(0,index2):
                    if column2==data4[k]:
                        count2+=1
                while count>0 or count2>0:
                    column2=random.randint(1,3)
                    for j in data2:
                        if row2 == j:
                            count += 1
                    for k in range(0, index2):
                        if column2 == data4[k]:
                            count2 += 1
                data4[index2]=column2
                block[row2-1][column2-1] = tac
            else:
                row2=random.randint(1,3)
                data3.append(row2)
                index1=0
                for j in data1:
                    if row2==j:
                        count+=1
                while count>0:
                    count=0
                    row2=random.randint(1,3)
                    data3[0]=row2
                    for j in data1:
                        if row2 == j:
                            count += 1
                column2=random.randint(1,3)
                data4.append(column2)
                index2=0
                count = 0
                for j in data2:
                    if row2 == j:
                        count += 1
                while count>0:
                    count=0
                    column2=random.randint(1,3)
                    data4[0]=column2
                    for j in data2:
                        if row2 == j:
                            count += 1
                block[row2 - 1][column2 - 1] = tac
            #block[row2-1][column2-1]=tac
            print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
            print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
            print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
        elif i%2==0:
            print('## Your Turn ##')
            row1=int(input("Row --> "))
            data1.append(row1)
            column1=int(input("Column --> "))
            data2.append(column2)
            block[row1-1][column1-1]=tic
            print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
            print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
            print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
        else:
            print("Draw!!")
            break
else:
    print("## A.I won the toss ##")
    print("## A.I ##")
    row2=random.randint(1,3)
    data3.append(row2)
    index1=0
    column2=random.randint(1,3)
    data4.append(column2)
    index2=0
    block[row2-1][column2-1]=tac
    print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
    print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
    print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
    while True:
        i+=1
        if block[0][0]==block[0][1] and block[0][1]==block[0][2] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[1][0]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[1][2] and block[1][0]!=' ':
            if block[1][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print('you Lose!!')
            break
        elif block[2][0]==block[2][1] and block[2][1]==block[2][2] and block[2][0]!=' ':
            if block[2][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][0]==block[1][0] and block[1][0]==block[2][0] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][1]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][1] and block[0][1]!=' ':
            if block[0][1]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][2]==block[1][2] and block[1][2]==block[2][2] and block[0][2]!=' ':
            if block[0][2]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][0]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][2] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][2]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][0] and block[0][2]!=' ':
            if block[0][2]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif i%2==0:
            print("## A.I ##")
            row2=random.randint(1,3)
            data3.append(row2)
            index1+=1
            length1 = len(data3)
            for j in data1:
                if row2==j:
                    count+=1
            for k in range(0,index1):
                if row2==data3[k]:
                    count2+=1
            while count>0 or count2>0:
                count=0
                count2=0
                row2=random.randint(1,3)
                for j in data1:
                    if row2 == j:
                        count += 1
                for k in range(0,index1):
                    if row2==data3[k]:
                        count2+=1
            data3[index1]=row2
            count=0
            count2=0
            column2=random.randint(1,3)
            data4.append(column2)
            index2+=1
            length2 = len(data4)
            for j in data2:
                if column2==j:
                    count+=1
            for k in range(0,index2):
                if column2==data4[k]:
                    count2+=1
            while count>0 or count2>0:
                count=0
                count2=0
                column2=random.randint(1,3)
                for j in data2:
                    if column2 == j:
                        count += 1
                for k in range(0,index2):
                    if column2==data4[k]:
                        count2+=1
            data4[index2]=column2
            block[row2-1][column2-1]=tac
            print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
            print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
            print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
        elif i%2!=0:
            print("## Your Turn ##")
            row1=int(input("Row --> "))
            data1.append(row1)
            column1=int(input("Column --> "))
            data2.append(column2)
            block[row1-1][column1-1]=tic
            print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
            print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
            print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
        else:
            print("Draw!!")
            break
print("Thanks for playing!!")
```

Comment: Start with a game loop. Think about run game logic after u start ur game loop. Try looking on GitHub for python tic tac toe games. Search for the keyword game loop and find an example. I will leave u an answer in 2 days if know one gets to it by then.

Comment: Thanks for the help @BlackFox much appreciated. But i want to make this game on my own logic when i try to see on the internet I get different logics but I want to make it with my logic thats how I can learn it and enjoy it yeah if i don't get the result after many tries then I will consider looking for other logics. I just made this code yesterday in about 5 hours.Looking forward for your help after 2 days. Thanks!! and also I will look for game loops on the internet and see if I can make my loop better.

Comment: I will create my game loop off this example: https://inventwithpython.com/chapter10.html

Comment: @BlackBox ok so i saw that code at a glance and it's logic was much like mine but I feel bad that I took like 300 lines whereas he took only 187 lines.Still I need to understand much of that code so if you can explain that code to me it would be great if you have time!!

Comment: @GIPSY_PIPSY I am working on an answer for you right now. I found the source of the problem. You are getting an infinite loop with ```while count > 0 or count2 > 0:```

Comment: @BlackFox how is it infinite loop for instance consider that row1=2 and row2=2 so the count=1 now the while loop will run now again count=0 and row2 gets a random value for an instance consider row2=1 so the loop terminates as count=0 now if row2 had again got row2=2 then the for loop had run and count=1 so again the while loop had run.   So its the logic

Comment: wait what is wrong with it?

Comment: @GIPSY_PIPSY what was your thought process for all the ```while count > 0 or count2 > 0: ``` loops? I'm trying to understand your logic. It gets hard to follow when I start reading that part.

Comment: @cwbusacker ok so my thought process for that staement was to check whether the random row or column that computer gets does not matches with previously filled ones.

Comment: @DontBe3Greedy just run the code and you will know the error and if not then plz tell me!!☺️

Comment: Thanks @cwbusacker  sorry for my mistake the code was wrong and thank you for your suggestion cwbusacker i saw that while loop again and again and felt that it had no need there i changed the code a bit and guess what it is working fine. I will post the new code so you may check it out.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the code a bit and removed the while loops instead i replaced it with another while loop in which it checks whether the  place with that row and column has white space or not if not then the column keeps on changing randomly until a place comes where there is a white space.Now for the row i simply checked whether the whole row is occupied or not if it is then the row keeps on changing randomly.This whole logic was changed for just the computer's turn.and guess what i reduced the code from 300 lines to 188 lines like 50%

Also changed the logic for draw it was rekt basically it just now checks whether all the places are not white spaces if yes then it gives *draw*

**The Improved Code**

```
import random
row1=None
column1=None
row2 = None
column2 = None
print("Welcome to TIC-TAC-TOE!!")
tic=input("Enter O or X as your choice --> ")
if tic=='O':
    tac='X'
else:
    tac='O'
block=[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]
i=0
choice=int(input("Enter 1 for Head and 0 for Tail --> "))
x=random.randint(0,1)
if choice==x:
    print("You won the toss you get the first chance : ")
    print("## Enter the row and column you want to put your choice in ##")
    row1=int(input("Row --> "))
    column1=int(input("Column --> "))
    block[row1-1][column1-1]=tic
    print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
    print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
    print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
    index1=0
    index2=0
    while True:
        i+=1
        if block[0][0]==block[0][1] and block[0][1]==block[0][2] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[1][0]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[1][2] and block[1][0]!=' ':
            if block[1][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print('you Lose!!')
            break
        elif block[2][0]==block[2][1] and block[2][1]==block[2][2] and block[2][0]!=' ':
            if block[2][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][0]==block[1][0] and block[1][0]==block[2][0] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][1]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][1] and block[0][1]!=' ':
            if block[0][1]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][2]==block[1][2] and block[1][2]==block[2][2] and block[0][2]!=' ':
            if block[0][2]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][0]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][2] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][2]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][0] and block[0][2]!=' ':
            if block[0][2]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif i%2!=0:
            print("## A.I ##")
            if row2!=None and column2!=None:
                row2=random.randint(1,3)
                while block[row2-1][0]!=' ' and block[row2-1][1]!=' ' and block[row2-1][2]!=' ':
                    row2=random.randint(1,3)
                column2=random.randint(1,3)
                while block[row2-1][column2-1]!=' ':
                    column2=random.randint(1,3)
            else:
                row2=random.randint(1,3)
                column2=random.randint(1,3)
                while block[row2-1][column2-1]!=' ':
                    column2=random.randint(1,3)
            block[row2-1][column2-1]=tac
            print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
            print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
            print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
        elif i%2==0:
            print('## Your Turn ##')
            row1=int(input("Row --> "))
            column1=int(input("Column --> "))
            block[row1-1][column1-1]=tic
            print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
            print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
            print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
        if block[0][0]!=' ' and block[0][1]!=' ' and block[0][2]!=' ' and block[1][0]!=' ' and block[1][1]!=' ' and block[1][2]!=' 'and block[2][0]!=' ' and block[2][1]!=' 'and block[2][2]!=' ':
            print("Draw!!")
            break
else:
    print("## A.I won the toss ##")
    print("## A.I ##")
    row2=random.randint(1,3)
    column2=random.randint(1,3)
    block[row2-1][column2-1]=tac
    print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
    print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
    print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
    while True:
        i+=1
        if block[0][0]==block[0][1] and block[0][1]==block[0][2] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[1][0]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[1][2] and block[1][0]!=' ':
            if block[1][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print('you Lose!!')
            break
        elif block[2][0]==block[2][1] and block[2][1]==block[2][2] and block[2][0]!=' ':
            if block[2][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][0]==block[1][0] and block[1][0]==block[2][0] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][1]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][1] and block[0][1]!=' ':
            if block[0][1]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][2]==block[1][2] and block[1][2]==block[2][2] and block[0][2]!=' ':
            if block[0][2]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][0]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][2] and block[0][0]!=' ':
            if block[0][0]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif block[0][2]==block[1][1] and block[1][1]==block[2][0] and block[0][2]!=' ':
            if block[0][2]==tic:
                print("You Win!!")
            else:
                print("You Lose!!")
            break
        elif i%2==0:
            print("## A.I ##")
            row2=random.randint(1,3)
            while block[row2 - 1][0] != ' ' and block[row2 - 1][1] != ' ' and block[row2 - 1][2] != ' ':
                row2 = random.randint(1, 3)
            column2=random.randint(1,3)
            while block[row2-1][column2-1]!=' ':
                column2=random.randint(1,3)
            block[row2-1][column2-1]=tac
            print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
            print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
            print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
        elif i%2!=0:
            print("## Your Turn ##")
            row1=int(input("Row --> "))
            column1=int(input("Column --> "))
            block[row1-1][column1-1]=tic
            print(block[0][0],"|",block[0][1],"|",block[0][2])
            print(block[1][0],"|",block[1][1],"|",block[1][2])
            print(block[2][0],"|",block[2][1],"|",block[2][2])
        if block[0][0]!=' ' and block[0][1]!=' ' and block[0][2]!=' ' and block[1][0]!=' ' and block[1][1]!=' ' and block[1][2]!=' 'and block[2][0]!=' ' and block[2][1]!=' 'and block[2][2]!=' ':
            print("Draw!!")
            break
print("Thanks for playing!!")
```

Comment: Sometimes it's nice to have a second pair of eyes point out where your flaws are. Really helps you figure it out on your own.

Comment: @cwbusacker Thanks for the suggestion man that's why i love coding community everyone helps each other.

Comment: @cwbusacker I posted this question cause i had my exams coming so i didn't wanted to give much time in it but I guess once I start a project I cannot help myself I need to complete it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modular version with added checks for correct functioning under ALL conditions:

```js
import random

def print_board(board):
    """Print the Tic-Tac-Toe board"""
    print(board[0][0], "|", board[0][1], "|", board[0][2])
    print("--+---+--")
    print(board[1][0], "|", board[1][1], "|", board[1][2])
    print("--+---+--")
    print(board[2][0], "|", board[2][1], "|", board[2][2])
    
def get_player_choice(board, player):
    """Get the row and column where the player wants to place their mark"""
    while True:
        try:
            row = int(input(f"Player {player}, enter the row number (1-3): "))
            column = int(input(f"Player {player}, enter the column number (1-3): "))
            if not (1 <= row <= 3 and 1 <= column <= 3):
                raise ValueError("Invalid row or column number")
            if board[row-1][column-1] != " ":
                raise ValueError("That cell is already occupied")
            return row-1, column-1
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

def has_won(board, player):
    """Check if the player has won the game"""
    for i in range(3):
        # Check rows
        if board[i][0] == board[i][1] == board[i][2] == player:
            return True
        # Check columns
        if board[0][i] == board[1][i] == board[2][i] == player:
            return True
    # Check diagonals
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == player:
        return True
    if board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == player:
        return True
    return False

def play_game():
    """Play a game of Tic-Tac-Toe"""
    print("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!")
    board = [[" "]*3 for _ in range(3)]
    players = ["X", "O"]
    random.shuffle(players)
    print(f"The first player is {players[0]}")
    while True:
        for player in players:
            print_board(board)
            row, column = get_player_choice(board, player)
            board[row][column] = player
            if has_won(board, player):
                print_board(board)
                print(f"Player {player} has won the game!")
                return
            if all(board[i][j] != " " for i in range(3) for j in range(3)):
                print_board(board)
                print("It's a tie!")
                return

play_game()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).